# Opening a byte stream to a nearby peer using GKSession

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, stream

There is a method from the MCSession Class called – startStreamWithName:toPeer:error:,
which allows one to open a byte stream to a nearby peer. An NSStream.

The problem is I'm using GKSession to start a session with a near by peer and there is no convince method for sharing an audio stream (NSStream) with them. I have to use GKSession because I'm writing an application in iOS6/iOS7. Was just wondering if anyone knew of a way, I could share a NSStream with a near by peer. using GKSession.

Thanks